# C# Math.Floor double with no decimal places gets rounded down. Sometimes

Tags: c#, double

I'm using Math.Floor to round a double down to no decimals.
This is working as expected, apart from some cases.
Sometimes, when the double doesn't have any decimal places, Math.Floor lowers the double by 1. So 2006 becomes 2005 for example. This doens't always happen, most of the times it doesn't change the value of the double. 2005 stays 2005.

Code snippet:

```
double dBuislengte = 0;
dBuislengte = swDispDim.GetDimension2(0).Value;
Debug.Print("d: " + dBuislengte);
dBuislengte = Math.Floor(dBuislengte);
Debug.Print("d Math.Floor: " + dBuislengte);
```

Output:

```
d: 436
d Math.Floor: 436
d: 1854,5
d Math.Floor: 1854
d: 1951,5
d Math.Floor: 1951
d: 2006
d Math.Floor: 2005
```

As you can see, the first output value is what I expect to happen and what happens most of the time. The last value shows the problem.

I can fix it by only do the Math.Floor operation on doubles with decimal places, but that won't help me understand what's going on.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: In the last case, the actual value is probably 2005.99999, which `Debug.Print` rounds up to 2006.

Comment: Thank you! It turns out in Solidworks' reality the number 2006 (millimeters) doesn't exist. It turns it into 2005999999.99999976nm and this doesn't show while working in millimeters. The API does return the real value.
Maybe it has to do with overflow of a value or something, my knowlegde doesn't reach that far.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TimB it's not that 2006 doesn't exist. It's simply some accumulating errors after a series of computation

Answer (score 0):

[@bbbbbbbbb commented with the right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70563955/c-sharp-math-floor-double-with-no-decimal-places-gets-rounded-down-sometimes/70567493#comment124737986_70563955):

> In the last case, the actual value is probably 2005.99999, which `Debug.Print` rounds up to 2006.

Answer (score 0):

First response here on stack overflow and very new to programming, but could you cast the result into an integer to round it?

```
dBuislengte = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(dBuislengte));
```